# fixed div with anchor navigation - breaking page

Tags: css, html, anchor

I have a div to the left of a page that contains links to different divs on the right. I want the left div to stay fixed when scrolling the page but also show next to the div I jump to. the problem is that when i click on a link it will jump to the div but the navigation div does not render until i mouse over it piece by piece and it seems to break the page. any ideas?

Navigation div

```
<div class="tableoutline fixed">
 <table class="notableoutline glossary">
  <thead>                               
  </thead>
  <tbody>
<tr>                
 <td class="datatd">
  <a href="#recommendedQuestions">{{data.learn.recommendedQuestions.title}}</a>                                     
 </td>                                  
</tr>
<tr>    
 <td class="datatd">            
  <a href="#process">{{process.title}}</a>                                      
 </td>                                  
</tr>
   </tbody>
 </table>
 </div> <!-- End of tableoutline -->
```

content div

```
<div class="contentbox bottomMargin" id="process" name="process">
 <h1>{{data.learn.process.title}}</h1>
  <div class="questionsAndAnswers">                     
   <h2>{{process.question1}}</h2>
   <p>{{process.answer1}}</p>       
  </div>                                
 </div> <!-- End of Content Box /-->
```

Comment: Please can you make a fiddle

Comment: we need a jsfiddle to help you

Answer (score 0):

to make an element fixed:

```
#element {
   position: fixed;
}
```

if you want it to be on top all the time, use **`z-index`**